# Is there a Standard card similar to Debt to the Deathless?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

With M15 around the corner I need a standard card that has a similar effect as [Debt to the Deathless](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Debt%20to%20the%20Deathless). Does anyone know a white, black, or green standard set card that works like this?

Answer (score 1):

The cards from Theros, Born of the Gods, Journey into Nyx, and Magic 2015 (the sets that will be standard when Khans of Tarkir releases in September and whose contents are currently known) with abilities of the form "Each opponent loses *n* life.  You gain life equal to the life lost this way." are as follows:

- [Gray Merchant of Asphodel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gray%20Merchant%20of%20Asphodel) — life loss equal to your devotion to black when it enters the battlefield
- [Scholar of Athreos](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Scholar%20of%20Athreos) — life loss of 1 via a 2B activated ability
- [Servant of Tymaret](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Servant%20of%20Tymaret) — life loss of 1 whenever it becomes untapped
- [Tormented Hero](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tormented%20Hero) — life loss of 1 whenever you cast a spell that targets it

There are no cards with this mechanic in Magic 2015, unless you count [Covenant of Blood](http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/tcg/products/m15/sf0JdVsk2/EN_ffn1gmrc7a.png).